# Reasoning approaches for implementing a Knowledge-based System?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, knowledge-representation, recommendation-systems, interactive-proof-systems, case-based-reasoning

What are the major approaches in implementing a Knowledge-based System (KBS)? Approaches used to take decisions in a KBS that I have come across so far are the case-based and rule-based reasoning approaches. I would like know about other approaches and implementations. I would appreciate any recommendation about helpful texts or websites or other resources.